# Using UIImages applyBlurWithRadius and it freezes my app for about 5 seconds?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiimage

I am using the UIIamges applyBlurWithRadius method, but it freezes my app for about 5 seconds. Why is this method such a memory hog and is there an alternative? Overall, I am trying to take UIImage blur it and then alpha it.

```
- (IBAction)updateImage:(id)sender
{
UIImage *effectImage = nil;
UIColor *tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.97 alpha:0.62];
effectImage = [self.image applyBlurWithRadius:13 tintColor:tintColor saturationDeltaFactor:1.8 maskImage:nil];

if(!Is_iPad){

    effectImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[effectImage CGImage] scale:1.0f orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];

}

self.bgImageView.image = effectImage;


}
```

//// UPDATE //////

I have added this which removes the freezing, but when the VC loads the image loads regular then after 5 seconds the blurred image is final shown (i.e. when applyBlurWithRadius is finished processing).

```
- (IBAction)updateImage:(id)sender
{
__block UIImage *effectImage = nil;

dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("com.stat.completionQueue", NULL), ^{

    UIColor *tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.97 alpha:0.62];
    effectImage = [self.image applyBlurWithRadius:13 tintColor:tintColor saturationDeltaFactor:1.8 maskImage:nil];

    if(!Is_iPad){
        effectImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[effectImage CGImage] scale:1.0f orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.bgImageView.image = effectImage;
    });
});
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the method which is freezing your app?

Comment: How large is `self.image`?

Comment: Takes up the entire screen. The image is one from my iPhone that I took with my iPhone.